# How do I verify that my CentOS Guest on a VMWare ESX Host is Using the vmware tools network driver?

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-esx

I can verify that vmware tools is running with `/etc/init.d/vmware-tools status`, but how can I verify that the vmware-tools network driver is being used by my CentOS guest?

The host is VMWare ESX 4.1

Perhaps I need to look for something in `lsmod`? I see a file in modprobe.d that contains:

```
install pcnet32 /bin/sh -c ". /usr/lib/vmware-tools/install/vmware-open-vm-tools-kmod/functions load-module && vmware_load_module vmxnet" || /sbin/modprobe                -q --ignore-install pcnet32 ; /bin/true
```

`lmsod` doesn't show a pcnet or vmxnet however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cat /etc/modprobe.conf and if you are using a vmnext NIC on your VM you will see a line aliasing vmnext3 (or vmnext) to eth0. You need to have the proper NIC configured on your VM for Linux to get the paravirtualized benefits of the vmnext NIC. If I remember correctly, if you just use the default (e1000) NIC you will be using the stock RHEL (CentOS) driver. Doing an lsmod would show the vmnext and vmnext3 drivers loaded but unless they are setup in modprobe.conf, you will not be using them.

Comment: +1 e1000 is the default in VM Hardware version 7 and is supported by  native drivers.

Comment: I am using the e1000 -- looking into this now.

Comment: So there is VMXNET 2 (Enhanced) and VMXNET 3.... Tough call .. one is enhanced but one has a higher number ... ?

Comment: VMNext3 is the latest iteration of the VMWare paravirtualized NIC. If you are using RHEL (or CentOS) 5 or 6 as well as Windows 2008, I would use VMNext3. Just remember, the VM has to be configured at the VMWare level to use the vmnext NIC, just enabling the driver without actually making the NIC a vmnext NIC in VMWare will not work.

Comment: Kyle if you're using those Intel NICs you moved your Windows boxes to in your ESXi host then you're better off with the vmxnet3 driver, much lower host resource utilisation and lower latency.

Answer (score 1):

In the VSClient just look at the individual VM's summary, it lists whether or not the vmtools are fully and properly installed and up to date.

Comment: It says "Unmanaged". Also, when I sourced that vmware-open-tools... library in bash and then run load_module it says there is no such function.... However if I go after the `&&` and just run `vmware_load_module vmxnet` that loads the module in lsmod.

Comment: :( have you rebooted since installing the vmtools? you need to - if you have then they've not gone in properly sorry. Essentially they just get installed and just work in my experience, especially with RHEL/OEL/Centos - very stable normally - how did you install them? virtual CD and the .pl file?

Comment: Using the `vmware-tools-repo` at `http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/4.1/rhel5/x86_64`. And yes, I have restarted.

Comment: oh ok, I've never used that as I use vCenter Update Manager... looks like it'd be the right kind of thing, odd that it says unmanaged though, that's not right

Comment: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1032763 "The "Unmanaged" status for VMware Tools indicates that a mechanism other than vSphere Client is used to keep the tools up-to-date." Is this guest some kind of appliance? I see this with the vi management and vidrs appliances

Comment: I see the same natxo - hence my concerns

Comment: I have now a better explanation. We use the open-vm-tools (you can find more info in http://www.vmware.com/download/packages.html) which you can install using the local linux package manager (yum, apt-get, ...). So the guest package manager is responsible for the vm-tools, not virtual center. Hence "unmanaged" by virtual center.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ethtool` to be sure:

```
$ sudo /sbin/ethtool -i eth0
driver: vmxnet3
version: 1.2.39.0-NAPI
firmware-version: N/A
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
```